# Preserving delivery order

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am considering using AMQP for an application where delivery order is paramount.

I cannot therefore use the normal re-delivery features, as undelivered messages are re-queued out of order.

It looks like what I must do is to leave the message on the queue until it has been processed, and then specifically delete it. It is then possible that the same message is processed twice in order, but that is easy to trap and deal with.

However, I don't see how to do this. What I am looking for is some sort of peek and delete message methods, giving me direct control, but they don't seem to exist.

Am I missing something, or trying to solve the problem in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have peek-and-delete in AMQP.  Actually, you cannot browse the messages on a queue without consuming them and Rabbit does not provide any extension to enable this.

The general response to your problem is "Think very carefully if you actually need that in-order constraint", because, for instance, with that constraint in place, you cannot have multiple consumers on a queue.

Comment: Unfortunately order preservation is really necessary, I said paramount and meant it. Looking at the docs, it looks like it may be possible to put non ack'd messages onto a separate recovery queue that the consumer checks at start time, not sure I understand that yet though...

Comment: You could do something like that, but then what do you do if the consumer dies when consuming from the dead-letter queue?  Adding another *queue* will just move the original problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I have been solving the same problem. In my solutions I have been **wrapping** the **messages into** one **single message** where the **outer message** has been **processed first** and **then** I have **processed** the **remaining inner messages** in the wrapped order. This has some disadvantages, for example big messages (once your wrapping hierarchy contains many messages), more difficult serialization, ..., but for me the solution was suitable enough.